# Custom Content Type with Custom Fields creation

Tags: 8

I followed the examples given at: https://www.drupal.org/node/2629550  to create a new content type.  No problems there, the content type exists after I install the module.  However, when I uninstall, and re-install with the custom field yml files it says to have, I get errors saying that the field storage doesn't exists.   So I dug into `core/modules/node/config/install`and copied the field.storage.body and modified it for the field I wanted (username).  The field created, however, when I install the module now... It says:

`Drupal\Core\Field\FieldException: Attempt to create a configurable field for a non-configurable field storage. in Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig->__construct() (line 94 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-8.4.4\drupal-8.4.4\core\modules\field\src\Entity\FieldConfig.php).`

Here is the yml for the custom content type:

```
#node.type.faculty_bio.yml
langcode: en
status: true
name: "Faculty Bio"
type: faculty_bio
description: "Faculty Bio"
help: ''
display_submitted: true
```

and the code for the custom field:

```
#field.field.node.faculty_bio.username.yml
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.body
    - node.type.faculty_bio
  module:
    - text
    - node
id: node.faculty_bio.username
field_name: field.storage.node.username
field_storage: username
entity_type: node
bundle: faculty_bio
label: Username
description: 'The username'
required: true
translatable: true
default_value: {}
default_value_callback: ''
settings:
  display_summary: true
field_type: text
```

Comment: Any certain reason why you are trying to create the content type programmatically? Just use core's Field UI module (/admin/structure/types) for a point and click interface. If you need the YML source you can export the configuration and copy them from the config sync directory into your module

Comment: @Hudri I need the content type to be created when a module is installed. I will also be creating custom nodes programmatically later on in the module (which I already know how to do)

Comment: Fastest way still is to create them on a dummy site with field UI, export live config, and copy corresponding files to your_module/config/install. Remember that one content type consists of several config files (at least node_type + fields + field_storage + view modes + form modes). [Drupal Console](https://drupalconsole.com/) has a special option `drupal config:export --remove-uuid --remove-config-hash` to create config files without the site-specific keys.

Comment: 2nd option would be [Features module](https://www.drupal.org/project/features), basically does the same as CLI tools above.

Comment: @Hudri ok so I did what you suggested, and flushed out the content type with the UI and did an export to get the yml for the content type.   It still doesn't give me the fields in the content type, which is what I need flushed out.   I need to be able to have that content type set up with a simple install of the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the content type in a test environment, and populated all of the fields I wanted using the UI.  Then I went to the site configuration and did an export on the entire site. I pulled all of the yml files I needed for the fields and node types, and it works beautifully.